# Converting a nested list into list shows unhashable type

Tags: python, list

How to convert a nested list into a separate list?

```
rec = [["A",["B","C","D"]],["B",["D","E","F"]],["C",["G","H","I"]]]
```

Desired output:

```
desired_output = [["A","B","C","D"],["B","D","E","F"],["C","G","H","I"]]
```

I've tried the below code, however, it throws a Type Error: - **unhashable type: 'list'**

```
data = list(set([tuple(row) for row in rec]))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[[x] + y for x, y in rec]` ?

Comment: Why are you using `set` if you're trying to make lists?

Comment: Removing unnecessary tags `data-science` and `pandas`.

Comment: @khelwood I'm using Set to deal with the duplicate elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work in your case where there is a single element followed by a list at each entry:

```
[[elem] + lst for elem, lst in rec]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just flatten the 2nd member of the pair, for each sublist

```
rec = [["A", ["B", "C", "D"]], ["B", ["D", "E", "F"]], ["C", ["G", "H", "I"]]]

result = [[first, *others] for first, others in rec]
print(result)  # [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['C', 'G', 'H', 'I']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
new_list = list()
for c in rec:
 new_list.append([a for b in c for a in b])
```